# Actions of rings (and other algebraic structures) on abelian categories

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

On the project I am currently working on, there are abelian, Krull-Schmidt categories $\mathcal{C}$ where it seems natural to equip $\mathcal{C}$ with the action of a ring $R$ (in some cases a semiring is better, but let us stick with rings for now).

Upon writing down a list of axioms for my family of categories equipped with these ring actions, I realised that many of my axioms were actually analogous to the axioms used in the definition of an $R$-module. Now this of course shouldn't be surprising, but it got me thinking:

An $R$-module is just an abelian group equipped with the action of a ring $R$. What happens when we replace 'abelian group' with 'abelian category'? Have such structures been studied in detail and (perhaps more importantly for me right now) do they have a name? I would be surprised if the haven't/didn't, but I have struggled to find anything in the literature thus far.

I am well aware of actions on groups on categories (especially module categories), and that there is an extensive theory of these. However, I am also unaware of any specific name for these beyond some special cases.

For some further details as to what I have/want:

(1) By an action of a ring (or semiring with additive and multiplicative identities) $R$ on $\mathcal{C}$, I mean a family of exact, additive endofunctors $\{r \cdot {-}\colon \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{C} | r \in R\} $ such that

(a) $r \cdot (X \coprod Y) \cong (r \cdot X) {\coprod} (r \cdot Y)$,

(b) $(r+s) \cdot X \cong (r \cdot X) {\coprod} (s \cdot X)$,

(c) $(rs) \cdot X \cong r \cdot (s \cdot X)$,

(d) $1_R \cdot X \cong X$,

(e) $0_R \cdot X \cong 0$,

where $r,s \in R$ and $X,Y$ are objects in $\mathcal{C}$,

(f) $r$ induces a homomorphism of abelian groups $H_r\colon\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,Y) \rightarrow \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(r\cdot X, r\cdot Y)$   (if $\mathcal{C}$ is a linear category, then I am inclined to say that this should be a linear map),

(g) $r$ induces a homomorphism of abelian groups $E_r\colon\mathrm{Ext}^1_{\mathcal{C}}(X,Y) \rightarrow \mathrm{Ext}^1_{\mathcal{C}}(r\cdot X, r\cdot Y)$   (again, if these have vector space structures, then I am inclined to say that this should be a linear map).

There may be more axioms that I need, but for now, *I think* these are ok.

(2) The categories I am specifically working with are actually hereditary module categories of unital associative algebras over algebraically closed fields. (Most of the ones I am considering have finitely many indecomposable objects, but I am also considering some wild algebras.) Thus, we can interpret the coproduct above as a direct sum $\oplus$ in the above list of axioms. However, I am still interested in the more general setting above.

**Edit:** @dhy has pointed out that the category $\mathcal{C}$ cannot both be Krull-Schmidt and have the ring action I have described. This may explain why I have not come across such structures in the literature before. I believe semiring actions should still work correctly, however.

A trivial example of the above action that I have described is the action of $R=\mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$ (viewed as a semiring) on $\mathcal{C}$. This can be defined such that $n\cdot X \cong \coprod_{i=1}^n X$ for any $n \in R$ and object $X \in \mathcal{C}$. I have other examples that are more interesting, but these are difficult to describe in detail in this format.

Comment: Can you give an example of such a category? In particular, the following seems strange to me: For any $X$ we have $(1+(-1))\cdot X=0\cdot X$, so if $X$ is nontrivial then $0\cdot X$ must also be nontrivial. This seems hard to reconcile with your axioms, though I don't see an immediate contradiction. (It certainly cannot hold in a Krull-Schmidt category.)

Comment: On the other hand, if what you are really interested in is the case where $R$ is a semi-ring, this is a natural notion (and recovers the case of group actions that you mention). Could you clarify which case you are interested in?

Comment: Maybe a more natural replacement (or enhancement) of "abelian group" in the categorical setting would be "Picard category".

Comment: @dhy This is perhaps a naive question, but is it possible for an abelian category to have multiple objects isomorphic to the zero object? I suppose there is only one map between  0 and (say) Z and vice versa, so the Hom group is trivial, but I don't immediately see a problem with this. Also, why can this not happen in a Krull-Schmidt category? Is this to do with the endomorphism rings being local? I suppose as well there may be some issues with the inclusions of the coproduct and now that I think about it... I believe I have a way to fix this, but it is complicated.

Comment: @dhy Yes, the case of the semiring is actually more natural. It is difficult to communicate the specifics via mathoverflow, as the best way for me to describe what I have is with an Aulsander-Reiten quiver! A very basic (and perhaps uninteresting) example is where we have the semiring of natural numbers (with zero) acting on an abelian category, where $n$ acts on an object X by taking it to $X \oplus \ldots \oplus X$ ($n$ times). I have more interesting actions in mind with extended integer rings on representation finite hereditary algebras, however.

Comment: @Iteraf The zero object is unique (up to isomorphism.) I'm not sure what category you are thinking of with both $0$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ (there are a few possible categories); in each of them only one of those two is a zero object. Re the Krull-Schmidt remark: Set $A=0\cdot X$. Then your axiom (b) gives $A=A\oplus A.$ In a Krull-Schmidt category this implies $A=0$, which in turn implies $X=0$ by the logic of my previous comment.

Comment: @Iteraf I think you will get better answers if you align the details in your question with the details in your comment.

Comment: @dhy apologies, I meant 'an object Z in $\mathcal{C}$', not the integers $\mathbb{Z}$. And yes, I will edit my question to focus more on semirings and provide more details

Comment: @dhy sorry once again actually. I find myself a little confused by the logic above. $A \cong A \oplus A \cong 0 \Rightarrow A \cong 0$, this I am fine with. Why does this imply $X \cong 0$ from your previous comment? I see that it (tautologically) implies $0 \cdot X \cong 0$ and this is fine. Why can we not have $1 \cdot X \not\cong 0$, $-1 \cdot X \not\cong 0$ along with $(1 - 1) \cdot X \cong 0 \cdot X \cong 0$? I don't think I see any contradiction arising from the Krull-Schmidt property. (Note that I say these objects are isomorphic, not equal in the strict sense of the word)

Comment: @dhy ok nevermind, now I see a problem with the Krull-Schmidt property (but for a different reason)! We have $(1+1 - 1 -1) \cdot X \cong (1 -1) \cdot X \cong 0$. This violates the property on the number of indecompoable summands being equal for isomorphic objects

Comment: @Iteraf A direct summand of a zero object must also be a zero object. (Indeed, if there were nontrivial maps to or from it, that would give nontrivial maps to or from the zero object.) So triviality of $X\oplus (-1)\cdot X$ implies triviality of $X$.